# Do graphic card drivers in Ubuntu Linux automatically update?

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

This is relating to the AMD Radeon 500 Series Graphics Cards, specifically the [Radeon RX 580](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-500-series/radeon-rx-500-series/radeon-rx-580).

Do graphic card drivers in Ubuntu Linux automatically update when I run the "Update Software" app. Or do I have to manually update graphic card drivers manually, for example, [at this link](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-500-series/radeon-rx-500-series/radeon-rx-580)?

Comment: Generally you don't need any AMD graphics drivers. These GPUs are directly supported by Linux kernel that gets updates. But if you want the PRO version, you insall and update it manually.

Comment: depends on how you installed it.

Comment: @Pilot6 I didn't install anything so it must be the kernel drivers that are currently enabled. If I do install the PRO version, and decide later on that I'm tired of manually updating, how do I uninstall and move to auto-updated kernel drivers?

Comment: Check the README for uninstall instructions. But it may be tricky.